# Scala implementation of mutable stack throwing exception

Tags: scala

Here is a mutable implementation of a Stack :

```
class LinkedStackGeneric {

  var first : NodeGeneric = _

  def isEmpty : Boolean  = {
    first == null
  }

  def push(itemName : Any) = {
    val oldFirst = first
    first = new NodeGeneric(itemName , oldFirst)
  } 

  def pop = {
    first = first.next

    first.itemName

  }

}

      class NodeGeneric(val itemName : Any , val next : NodeGeneric) {}

   println("*********** testing LinkedStackGeneric *****************")

       val generic = new LinkedStackGeneric
       generic.push("test")
       generic.push("here");
       println(generic.isEmpty)
       println(generic.pop);
       println(generic.isEmpty)
       println(generic.pop);
       println(generic.isEmpty)
```

When I run this code it produces the following :

```
*********** testing LinkedStackGeneric *****************
false
test
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at LinkedStackGeneric.pop(LinkedStackGeneric.scala:19)
    at StacksAndQueuesTest$.main(StacksAndQueuesTest.scala:37)
    at StacksAndQueuesTest.main(StacksAndQueuesTest.scala)
```

This is the line which causes the error :

```
println(generic.pop);
```

What is causing this exception, am I not pushing the items onto the stack correctly ? Since I push two items :

```
   generic.push("test")
   generic.push("here");
```

shouldn't this exception not be thrown ?

Comment: You should not be using `null` except when inter-operating with non-Scala code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your `pop` method. Your order of execution is causing the issue...

```
 def pop = {
    val ret  = first.itemName
    first = first.next
    ret
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second call to pop sets first to `null` and then you try and call the method `itemName` on that null value